# How to filter a list of sublists

Tags: python, list

So I have a list of lists and I want to remove the sublists that don't meet the requirements.

```
lst = [[57], [71], [87], [97], [99], [101], [103], [113], [114], [115], [128], [131], [137], [147], [156], [163], [186]]
spectrum = [0, 113, 128, 186, 241, 299, 314, 427]
```

Code I have tried and the result:

```
for sublist in lst:  
    if sum(sublist) not in spectrum:  
        sublist.pop()

>>> [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [113], [], [], [128], [], [], [], [], [], [186]]
```

Doesn't the sublist include it's square brackets? so why when I pop a sublist the brackets remain? How can I solve this? I also tried `lst.pop(sublist)` but it keeps some sublists that don't meet the requirements.

Comment: In future question, you should include **all** relevant information, in this case `spectrum` should have been included so that when a user is trying to check a valid solution for you, they could check it against real data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you want to [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) a list to only leave behind the items that pass a certain condition. There is a built-in for this, [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), combined with a [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) and we get:

```
lst = filter(lambda x: sum(x) in spectrum, lst)
```

This can also be written as a list-comprehension (as it says in the docs on filters):

```
lst = [x for x in list if sum(x) in spectrum]
```

Timing which is faster:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.Timer('filter(lambda x: sum(x) in spectrum, lst)', 'from __main__ import lst, spectrum').repeat()
[7.258743352344543, 7.146834532770029, 7.233350271593071]
>>> timeit.Timer('[x for x in lst if sum(x) in spectrum]', 'from __main__ import lst, spectrum').repeat()
[5.67072096449019, 5.8301157366216785, 5.674548399701351]
```

list-comprehension is faster in this case, but in general for more complex filtering using the [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) built-in is prefered.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to remove the sublists from the outer list? `sublist.pop(x)` will remove `x` th element from `sublist`, x defaulting to `len(sublist) - 1`.

```
for sublist in lst:
    if sum(sublist) not in spectrum:
        lst.remove(sublist)
```

Also an iterable (list in this case) **shouldn't be modified** when it's being iterated through.

```
result_list = []
for sublist in lst:
    if sum(sublist) in spectrum:
        result_list.append(sublist)
```

This is more concise (and not a bit less pythonic)

```
lst = [sublist for sublist in lst if sum(sublist) in spectrum]
```

Comment: i already tried lst.remove(sublist) and lst.pop(sublist) and they both keep some sublists that they shouldn't.

Comment: @fractal_7: May be because in the for loop we are modifying the same list we are iterating through. Are you sure, the second (list comprehension) doesn't work?

Comment: well to be honest, i just checked it and yes the comprehension is correct, gives the same result as filter and in the same time.

Comment: @InbarRose: Are you sure? I checked this multiple times after your comment!

Comment: but the first for loop with lst.remove is wrong so you may want to delete it.